# Any examples of how to 'enable' Kotlin extension functions in Maven dependencies?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin-extension

I'm getting started with Kotlin and now trying to use the Kotlin-JDBC sample (https://github.com/kotlin-projects/kotlin-jdbc) and have added the following dependency to my Kotlin/Maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.451</version>
</dependency>
```

However, none of the extension functions appear in IntelliJ:

```
val dataSource : DataSource = JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:h2:mem:KotlinJdbcTest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "user", "password")
if ( dataSource != null ) {
    dataSource.update("create table foo (id int primary key, name varchar(100))")
}
```

'update' appears in red in my IDE.  Any idea on how to fix this?